# useragent: list of fake_useragent's possibilies and creating a precise useragent

Tags: python, user-agent

## Context

I am currently using the python library **fake_useragent** for modifying the useragent in **Selenium webdriver**. I would like to interact quite accurately with this information. I checked on the github of the library and also on internet but I cannot find a way to interact precisely with all the propositions of useragent.

## Questions

1. I notice the /tmp/fake_useragent_x.x.x.json file which contains a list of all the possibles useragent . Is it a convenient way to get those information in python and use it?
2. Does somebody also know how is it possible to get a precise combination for an useragent? For example, how could i combine the choice of a device, with an OS, and also a browser? Solutions related to other practices than this library are of course welcome

Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: Not sure about selenium but this one can make requests with any user agent you want:  pip install proxy-requests. You would have to parse html yourself though just like with requests module

Comment: Well, thanks for the library which seems to be really interesting for the use of proxy. However, my question is more about finding a provider of user-Agent in python. I think I am going to modify my question for letting the aims goes out , haha

Comment: Okay... an example of it's use just in case.. this one reads in from from a list of random user-agents: https://github.com/rootVIII/forum_bot